# how to implement search method for searching of string from PDF file in ipad

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Actually  i am loading a pdf file in a view.
I have a search button when I enter the string I want it to search that string  in entire pdf file and display it.
Can anyone tell me how to implement or Any sample code???

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it using this sample code available [here](https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit)